# What is included in the System Backup

Tags: backup

What exactly is included in the System backup found under System>Tools>Backups?

Comment: Maybe someone would like to add the tag "Backups" and re-tag this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the version.

- For **CE 1.5 and lower**  you can only back-up your database.
- **In version CE 1.6** you can back-up your `media` folder also along with the database, and you can back-up the file system of your Magento instance. All files and folders.
- **Starting CE 1.7**, in addition to what CE 1.6 offers, you can choose to back-up your file system without the `media` folder.

Comment: Also worth noting is that soft-links are not followed. So a full backup where the media directory is linked to a dir somewhere outside the web root will no actually include the media.

Comment: Thanks, but do you know what "file system" means exactly? Does it backup all the files in the Magento installation or something.

Comment: "File system" means the root of your installation except the following  `.svn`, `maintenance.flag, `var/session`, `var/cache`, `var/full_page_cache`, `var/locks`, `var/log`, `var/report`, and `media` if you choose to ignore it. You can find the list of ignored files and folders in here: `Mage_Backup_Helper_Data::getBackupIgnorePaths()`.

Comment: Seemingly to do a full backup you need to do both "System" and database as the "System" backup doesn't include Db files

Comment: @byronyasgur, the db is also backed up inside the tgz in var\xxxx_db.gz